# Saying Va'yechulu with a woman

Tags: shabbat, minhag, women, maariv, edim-witnesses

The Mishna Brurah 268:19 writes that one should say va'yachulu with two people minimum since there are those who hold you can't say it by yourself (he does note that one can read by himself if done as just reading from the Torah, and not done as testimony).

My question is if someone comes home and missed vayachulu with 2 can he and his wife say it together? Is a woman counted as a witness regarding this matter of testimony for vayachulu? After, all, for most things for which two witnesses are required, women do not count as witnesses.

Text of Mishna Brura: ‏{יט} ומעומד - לפי שבזה אנו מעידים להקב״ה במעשה בראשית ודין עדים בעמידה כדכתיב ועמדו שני האנשים וטוב לומר אותה ביחד בצבור דעדה שלמה בעינן להעיד להקב״ה ועכ״פ יהיה בשנים. ויחיד המתפלל י״א דאינו חוזר לומר ויכלו דאין עדות ליחיד וי״א דיחיד יכול לומר אבל אין צריך עמידה וטוב שגם היחיד יאמר אבל לא יתכוין לשם עדות אלא כקורא בתורה.‏

Comment: This is the wayehulu of qiddush or in maariv for Friday night?

Comment: After shmoneh esrei by maariv

Comment: @Aaron It's a khaf not a heth: "waykhullu"

Comment: We have a rule that where a woman is a valid witness a single witness us also good. So if we require two then a woman shouldn't be good.

Comment: If we take it at face value that it's actually testimony, wouldn't it be false testimony, since we weren't there to witness it?

Comment: It's a mistake to think that shabbas is a past idea,the meforshim explain that shabbas is a recurring idea weekly and that's why it makes someone a Jew, so every week it's a new testimony for that shabbas

Comment: @sam, that doesn't mean that we personally witnessed the things stated in VaYechulu.

Comment: @SethJ well, considering that the "testimony" is not being done at night, and not in front of a court, it's hard to imagine anyone considered this case to be actual testimony. As I often joke, how do we even know if this is a davar shebe'ervah, dinei mamonos or nefashos, that require two? Maybe this is a matter of issur ve'heter, where an eid echad neeman?

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/6131

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pesach Hadvir 268:7 - line 10](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7976&st=&pgnum=161) says that since Vayechulu is a Eidus that is well known, even ladies can be witnesses for this. On line 15 he says that a man and lady can say it together.

[Kaf Hachaim 268:36](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9086&st=&pgnum=95&hilite=) mentions this source.

Comment: Great answer,thanks,in the Kaf Hachaim he brings a shitta not like that but doesn't go with it